# Puppeteer proxy connection with VPN Gate

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I've been starting a small project on Node.js and Puppeteer that requires the use of a proxy and i've had some problem connecting through VPNGate's proxy servers.

this is the code i've used so far:

```
async function getIpTest(){
  ips= await new ipGeneration(40);
  console.log(ips['#HostName']);
  proxConnect= '--proxy-server=' + ips['#HostName'] + '.opengw.net';

  const browser= await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
    args: [proxConnect]
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({'Proxy-Authorization': 'Basic' + Buffer.from('vpn:vpn').toString('base64')});
  await page.goto('http://www.whatsmyip.org/');
}
```

where

```
IPGeneration()
```

is just a module i made to parse their CSV file.

and

```
proxConnect= '--proxy-server=' + ips['#HostName'] + '.opengw.net';
```

is part of the parsing and yeld same results if i put as string directly in puppeteer.launch args

I tried changing the port, or not using any. I tried a dozen of different proxy adresses, and tried to connect directly to IP or hostname

I've tried to look everywhere online but can't seem to find why it is not working (should i mention everything works without trying to launch puppeteer with the proxy).

Is it just VPN Gate that won't work with puppeteer?

EDIT: i was messing around and see that they have config data to connect through openVPN. Could it be a simple working solution to use node>openVPN>VPN Gate servers? Ill try this now

Comment: is there no solution?